# Why is there an extra & to pass the address of a non-static member function to a thread in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, pointer-to-member

As I understand, the name of a function itself serves as a pointer to it.

Therefore, when I have a function, I can create a thread by simply passing its address to the thread constructor, like below:

```
void thread_function {

}

std::thread threadObj1(thread_function);
```

My confusion is while passing the address of a non-static member function to a thread. For example:

```
class ClassA
{
  public:
  void nonstatic_function()
  {

  }
};

ClassA instance;
std::thread threadObj2(ClassA::nonstatic_function, &instance);
```

Passing the address of such a function is done in two ways:

```
ClassA::nonstatic_function

&ClassA::nonstatic_function
```

Why is there an extra `&`? If it is indeed needed, then how come the compiler does not complain even without it?

Comment: I believe you are passing by reference

Comment: Kindly elaborate. I am not talking about &instance.

Comment: For non-member functions, the name of the function serves as a pointer to it. The rules for member functions aren’t so lax — despite some sloppy compilers, the rule is that you have to say `&class_name::function_name` to get the address of a member function.

Comment: Are you using MSVC or mingw-w64 by any chance?

Comment: @MM, yes it is mingw-w64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I understand, the name of a function itself serves as a pointer to it.

This behaviour was inherited from C and  only applies to free functions or static member functions.

For non-static member functions there is no implicit conversion to pointer-to-member. A pointer-to-member is a fundamentally different thing from a free function pointer because it can't be called without also providing an object instance.

> If it is indeed needed, then how come the compiler does not complain even without it?

I guess you are using a compiler with a non-standard extension to allow the `&` to be omitted in this case. I believe older versions of MSVC allowed it to be omitted; and [gcc/Windows defaults to allowing this for MSVC compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554567/).

Comment: Got it, I better follow the standard and put a & in front of a static/non-static member function.

Answer (score 0):

`std::bind` helps you.

```
ClassA instance;
std::thread threadObj2(std::bind(&ClassA::nonstatic_function, &instance));
```